# Is there any option to defer the admission if accepted at a grad school?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, engineering

I'm a sophomore in masters in chemical engineering and I wanted to apply to grad schools in USA and Canada for PhD. The thing is, my program here for masters is not time bound. It may take me between 1 to 2 years more to complete and this can't be predicted as it all depends on various factors like how fast the research project goes and how good is the funding this year etc.

I wanted to know if universities provide you right to defer the admission (if they accept the application in the first place) for a semester or two.

Comment: My sense is that this is *generally* not allowed (but my experience is in the humanities), because admissions is done on a yearly basis. But rather than depending on strangers on the internet, why not check with schools you are interested in?

Comment: @xLeitix, Although the question you are directing me to is on the similar grounds but my situation is lot more different. See, I'd still be working on my current degree if and when I'm accepted for a PhD program. If I apply late (say,next year), I run the risk of waiting for 6 months before I start the doctoral program. Even for the safer side, if I apply after 6 months from now for spring semester admissions, my scope will be limited as not many universities have a spring intake. All these things in mind compelled me to put the question as I believe that it is not redundant.

Comment: Your personal situation is kind of irrelevant, as your question is really quite straight-forward: do universities allow deferring? I feel the answers in the linked question actually answer your question pretty well (e.g., @Suresh: *"You could defer admission, but it's a little unusual to defer for a year."*).

Comment: I don't know how it works elsewhere, but my department (a large mathematics department) seems to have no difficulty allowing grad students to defer their admission for a year. Longer deferments are problematic because of uncertainties about future funding. A shorter deferment, for one semester, is not an administrative problem but an educational one: Several of the standard courses for new Ph.D. students are two-semester sequences, and the first half of the sequence is offered only in the fall term.